# How can I get the real value from a bytearray?

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I relied my arduino card to my PC to get informations from it then process data with python. I found a code on internet it's really complicated for me but only one part of it is really giving me hard time, I explain :

First on the arduino card I send data to the PC with this function, there are 9 differents data :

```
void sendToPC(double* data1, double* data2, double* data3, 
          double* data4, double* data5, double* data6,
          double* data7, double* data8, double* data9)
{
    byte* byteData1 = (byte*)(data1);
    byte* byteData2 = (byte*)(data2);
    byte* byteData3 = (byte*)(data3);
    byte* byteData4 = (byte*)(data4);
    byte* byteData5 = (byte*)(data5);
    byte* byteData6 = (byte*)(data6);
    byte* byteData7 = (byte*)(data7);
    byte* byteData8 = (byte*)(data8);
    byte* byteData9 = (byte*)(data9);
    byte buf[36] = {byteData1[0], byteData1[1], byteData1[2], byteData1[3],
             byteData2[0], byteData2[1], byteData2[2], byteData2[3],
             byteData3[0], byteData3[1], byteData3[2], byteData3[3],
             byteData4[0], byteData4[1], byteData4[2], byteData4[3],
             byteData5[0], byteData5[1], byteData5[2], byteData5[3],
             byteData6[0], byteData6[1], byteData6[2], byteData6[3],
             byteData7[0], byteData7[1], byteData7[2], byteData7[3],
             byteData8[0], byteData8[1], byteData8[2], byteData8[3],
             byteData9[0], byteData9[1], byteData9[2], byteData9[3]};
    Serial.write(buf, 36);
    }
```

Then I take it back on the PC with Python and I obtain something like that :

```
self.rawData = bytearray(b'?\x00\x00\xf0A\x00\x00\xf0A\x00\x00\xf0A\x00\x00\xa0A\x00\x00\xa0A\x00\x00\xa0A\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x80')
```

In this bytearray there are 9 values with 4 bytes each one, now I want to convert it in real numbers to be able to use it, this is an example for the first value :

```
value1 = struct.unpack("f", self.rawData[0:4])
```

My problem is that way of proceeding give me numbers like -1.0842105735386007e-19 which are totally differents of the one sent by the arduino card (I'm supposed to receive values like 9.5 or -0.04, never values so small with e-19). Do you have an idea of what is wrong with my code?

Great thanks, I 'm not used to using python a lot, so I'm pretty bad bud I really need to solve this problem for my studies.

Comment: This could be an endianness problem.  Try reversing the byte strings before unpacking them.  I did this with some of your data and got more reasonable numbers.  But I haven't done the analysis to prove that this is the problem.

Comment: I understood the problem! But don't really know how to resolve it... I tried what you said and it worked but not all the time, then I understood that there is a lag between the data sent by the arduino card and the data received by python. For example if the Arduino send \xA\xB\xC\xD, python will receive \xB\xC\xD\xA or \xC\xD\xA\xB. So this is a probleme of coherence of time between arduino and python but I have no idea how to solve it, do you?

Comment: Sorry, no, I can only suggest that you ask on an Arduino forum, as it now sounds like a low-level problem.  I see there is [such a forum](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) on Stack Exchange.